# Create 2 images responsive layout in Tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

I just want to show 2 images just next to each other in tailwindcss, when using grid with 2 columns, they're not next to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-8">
  <img src="/img/logo.svg" class="h-6" alt="img1" />
  <img src="/img/logo.svg" class="h-6" alt="img2" />
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/TEgmJBkDQR You Can see that in the online editor using this link